# Material UI and TypeScript: How to use !important?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss

I'm building a React application and I'm using Material UI for my components. I wonder how I can give an `!important` property to a style?

I tried this:

```
<Paper className="left"...>
```

I'm using [`withStyles` and `WithStyles`](https://mui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles).
Then in my `styles.ts`:

```
left: {
  display: "block",
  float: "left!important",
},
```

But this throws the error:

```
[ts] Type '"left!important"' is not assignable to type '"right" | "none" | "left" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "inline-end" | "inline-start" | undefined'.
index.d.ts(1266, 3): The expected type comes from property 'float' which is declared here on type 'CSSProperties'
(property) StandardLonghandProperties<TLength = string | 0>.float?: "right" | "none" | "left" | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "inline-end" | "inline-start" | undefined
```

How would one assign an `!important` flag when using material-ui with TypeScript?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can just cast it. For example:

```
left: {
  display: "block",
  float: "left!important" as any,
},
```

or

```
left: {
  display: "block",
  float: "left!important" as "left",
},
```

Here's a [playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20CSSProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20%22block%22%20%7C%20%22inline%22%0A%20%20%20%20float%3A%20%22left%22%20%7C%20%22right%22%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test1%3A%20CSSProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20%22block%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20float%3A%20%22left%20!important%22%2C%20%2F%2F%20this%20is%20the%20problem.%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test2%3A%20CSSProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20%22block%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20float%3A%20%22left%20!important%22%20as%20any%2C%20%2F%2F%20works%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20test3%3A%20CSSProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20display%3A%20%22block%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20float%3A%20%22left%20!important%22%20as%20%22left%22%2C%20%2F%2F%20works%0A%7D).

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner way is to write a helper method:

```
function important<T>(value: T): T {
  return (value + ' !important') as any;
}
```

```
const MyComponent = styled('div')({
  fontWeight: important('bold'),
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me

```
<Toolbar
        sx={{
          minHeight: '0 !important',
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to overstyle a MUI component. Simplest and straight forward is to apply a stlye on the component itself. an inline styled weights more specifity then the provided css. You would use it like this:

```
<Paper style={{display: 'block'}}...>
```

If you want to make use of normal CSS:

```
import './style.css'
```

and provide a class on the component

```
<Paper className="left"...>
```

By this you will be able to use normal css like

```
left: {
  display: "block",
  float: "left!important",
},
```

I really recommand to think about the specifity and what to achieve with your styles, before you implement them, otherwise you will start a fight against MUI styles and this can get pretty nasty.
Hopefully this helps, happy coding ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I might have worded my question wrong. I did exactly what you described (with the className). The problem is that the line with float throws the error in my question. And this has something to do with TypeScript. I added this information to my question

Comment: ok, i didnt know you do with style. i set ExperimentalDecorators to true in tsconfig, to make use of recompose decorator syntax like this: ```@(compose(withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })) as any)``` https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose

Comment: maybe, for sakes of simplicity, you shuild remove the float from the class and put it into a style tag, but without important: `<Paper style={{float: 'left'}}...>`